# Non UTF 8 characters in JSON

Tags: java, json, utf-8

I have an upstream application sending me a JSON which contains non-UTF8 characters. I am not able to identify it. My API is just a passthrough service, hence we send it to another downstream API. It rejects the request with the error "JSON contains non UTF8 character". All APIs are coded in JAVA.

1. I would like to know how I can simulate the downstream error by mocking the non-UTF8 character in a test JSON file.
2. Will this line of code ensure that my request to downstream does not have non-UTF8 characters in it?
   `String utf8checkedRequestBody = new String(upstreamRequestBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));`
3. I will also set the Content-Type to my call to downstream API as `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

I understand that non-UTF8 characters can be simulated by shifting the bytes, but any help to achieve it in JAVA will be highly appreciated. My search in SO and web, did not yield any good answers :(

Comment: Send your json data to downstream using JSON.stringify(obj) .

Comment: As a side note: JSON must be UTF-8 encoded. Complain to upstream for such gross error. For your question: `\xC0` and `\FE` are bytes which should never be in a UTF-8 encoding. You may inject them.

Comment: Java normally has no notion of UTF-8 characters, because internally Java characters are already 16 bits wide characters. IMHO, the error suggests an encoding/decoding problem when you read the string from upstream or write it to downstream. As you show nothing of either, I cannot guess what could go wrong.

Comment: If you want to be super safe on output, you could escape all non ASCII characters as `"\uUUUU"`, using UTF-16 if you have characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. But that would not fix the upstream decoding problem.

Comment: UTF-8 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set. So, the characters are Unicode; the bytes are UTF-8. JSON characters are Unicode. JSON documents that are streamed or sent as files are supposed to be encoded with UTF-8, though UTF-16 and UTF-32 were allowed by the older standard. Any of the three is easily distinguished by a JSON library. But in general, it is part of the contract for effective communication for the sender and receiver of any kind of text to agree on the character encoding.